# Importing Csv file to postgres Cloud SQL instance invalid input syntax error

Tags: python, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, pgadmin

I am trying to import CSV file from my gcs to postgres database in cloud sql, then I connected through pgadmin and make the same columns but with different data types like sale_dollars type in postgres is double precision and in gcs its float,

when I am importing, I am getting this error and I am so confused I have tried to change the data type in pgadmin like real, integer but couldn't find the type of float.

**generic::failed_precondition: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type double precision: "sale_dollars" CONTEXT: COPY iowa_test_table, line 1, column sale_dollars: "sale_dollars"**

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to import the header row as if it were data. Tell copy to skip the header row, or just don't produce the header to start with.